# Hide item that is part of a loop based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
  <ul *ngFor="#item of items; #i=index" >
          <li [hidden]="{{ item.myattr === 'some_value' }}"> {{ item.val}} </li>

        </ul>
```

I have the following code shown above. I want hide the list if the item has a value equal some value. In this case I have the items, they have an attribute called `myattr`, and if it is equal to `some_value` then the item should be hidden. The code I provided though does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use interpolation `{{}}` with property binding `[]` (actually, you can't):

```
<li [hidden]="item.myattr === 'some_value'">
```

Also, read *Mistake #1:  Binding to the native "hidden" property* in http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

So a better solution is likely

```
<li *ngIf="item.myattr !== 'some_value'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use ng-hide also like;

```
<li ng-hide="item.myattr =='some_value'"> {{item.val}} </li>
```

assuming that item.myattr is the same type with some_value.

Comment: The question is about Angular (2), not AngularJS/1.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use pipe to filter out unneeded items.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html